# Windows update - network speed throttle

Tags: networking, windows-10, updates, bandwidth

What 'speed percentage' is referred in Windows update delivery optimization, 'interface' speed or broadband connection speed?
I ask this because I'm on a good LAN, but network connection is slow ~4Mbit/s, so I want to still be able to work even though Windows is updating.

Also is there a way to tell Windows to download updates at night because working time works only for install time and bandwidth is really limited.

Example: My PC has a gigabit ethernet card connected to a gigabit cable router, but with only a 4 megabit/s DSL. Does 5% refer to gigabit LAN speed, so 5% is 50 megabit/s (de facto useless in my case) or to DSL broadband so 5% is 200 kilobit/s, and lets me use the network while Windows is updating?

[image: limit bandwidth for Windows update using Settings]
<sup>**limit bandwidth for Windows update using Settings**</sup>

Comment: Why not simply try it out? The Windows Task Manager should allow you to see the current network utilization and it should be easy to figure out whenever that is within your expected parameters.

Comment: Because I tryed but it does not seems to have effect